# Algorithm - Maximum left sub-array with lesser elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am working on a program where I need to get the index of element in an array of integers such that all elements to the right of the index are greater than all the elements from `0` to that index position.

For example:

`Case : 1` - Given input - `{ 5, -2, 3, 8, 6 }` then I need the index position as `2 (i.e array element with value 3)` because all elements after index 2 are greater than all elements starting from index `0` to index `2` i.e {5,-2,3}

`Case : 2` - Given input - `{ -5, 3, -2, 8, 6 }` then I need the index position as `2 (i.e array element with value -2)` because all elements after index 2 are greater than all elements starting from index `0` to index `2` i.e {-5,3,-2}

Here is my Java program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = { 5, -2, 3, 8, 6 };
        int[] array2 = { -5, 3, -2, 8, 6 };
        process(array1);
        process(array2);
    }

    private static void process(int[] array) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int maxIndex = 0;
        list.add(array[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] <= Collections.max(list)) {
                list.add(array[i]);
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("index = " + maxIndex + ", element = " + array[maxIndex]);
    }
}
```

The program output is :

```
[5, -2, 3, 8, 6]
index = 2, element = 3
[-5, 3, -2, 8, 6]
index = 0, element = -5
```

It works for `case 1` but fails for `case 2`. Can you please help me in fixing this. Is there any other better way to solve this,

Comment: This algorithm is not working properly. You invented it by yourself or it comes from other site?

Comment: @ByeBye I just took a scenario and tried implementing it, it is working for few cases only

Comment: Because you need to compute all possib I suggest to sotre in a map, and get min at end

Comment: in `array2[0]` value is -5 (negative). in your 2nd example value is 5 (positive). so your program seems to work correctly (since index 1 > value of index 0)

Comment: In case 2 the array starts with 5 and in code the array2 starts with -5

Comment: But algorithm is still now working

Comment: why not get the index of the maximum element of the array? will not it be always the index? I am sorry this will not work, only works for the examples you provide.

Comment: Start from the end of the array right will only have one element and left will have n - 1 elements. Then check for the condition that maximum of left < minumum of right if this satisfies then it is done, else move the index to the left and check for this again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your solution has several logical mistakes. One of the counterexamples: `[2, 1, 3, 6, 5]` (your algorithm returns index `1`, but the answer is `2`).

I propose another solution with `O(n)` time complexity:

1. Iterate from left to the right calculating the maximum of elements in `[0..i]` interval.
2. Iterate from right to the left calculating the minimum of elements in `[i+1..n]` interval and comparing this minimum with the maximum of the elements to the left that were pre-calculated at the first step.

Sample implementation:

```
static void process(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    if (n < 2) return;

    int[] maxLeft = new int[n];
    maxLeft[0] = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        maxLeft[i] = Math.max(maxLeft[i-1], array[i]);
    }  

    int minRight = array[array.length-1];
    for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (maxLeft[i] < minRight) {
            System.out.println("index = " + i + ", element = " + array[i]);
            return;
        } 
        minRight = Math.min(minRight, array[i]); 
    }
}
```

Runnable: http://ideone.com/mmfvmH

Comment: just need to add a print case if the partition is from the (n-2)th element, example int[] array1 = { 3, -2, 3, -2, 3 };

Comment: @Hakes, but this case has no answer. From the question: "I need to get the index of element in an array of integers such that all elements to the right of the index are greater than all the elements from 0 to that index position".

Comment: Yes, you are right greater than, not greater or equal, my mistake.

Comment: @DAle, Thank you. Can you please suggest me a good book on algorithms, I tried learning from `coreman` but I am not able to understand anything from it.

Comment: @user3181365, you are welcome! "Introduction to Algorithms" is a great book, it was my personal choice once upon a time. May be some Robert Sedgewick or Niklaus Wirth books would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Changed my comment to answer. Start from the end of the array right will only have one element and left will have n - 1 elements. Then check for the condition that maximum of left < minumum of right if this satisfies then it is done, else move the index to the left and check for this again.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = { 5, -2, 3, 8, 6 };
        int[] array2 = { -5, 3, -2, 8, 6 };
        int[] array3 = { 1, 3, 5, 8, 4 };
        int[] array4 = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        process(array1);
        process(array2);
        process(array3);
        process(array4);
    }


    private static void process(int[] array) {
        List<Integer> listLeft = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> listRight = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //create an array that consists upto n-1 elements
        int arraySize = array.length;
        if ( arraySize < 2){
            System.out.println("None");
            return;
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++){
            listLeft.add ( array[i]);
        }
        //create an array that has the last element
        listRight.add ( array[arraySize - 1]);

        //iterate from the last adding new elements till the condition satisfies
        for ( int i = arraySize - 2; i >= 0; i--){

            //if the condition is satisfied exit
            if ( Collections.max(listLeft) < Collections.min(listRight)){
                System.out.println("index = " + i + ", element = " + array[i]);
                return;
            }else{
                //remove an element from left and add an element to right
                listLeft.remove (listLeft.size() - 1);
                listRight.add ( array[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("None");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an algorithm for getting the correct output. It will be executed in O(n). Let us consider there are `n` elements in `arr[]`. Maintain 2 arrays int `minElementIndex[]` and `maxElementIndex[]`.

- `minElementIndex[i]` stores the index of the minimum value element present in the subarray[(i+1) ... (n-1)]. The value of `minElementIndex[n-1]=n-1`
- `maxElementIndex[i]` stores the index of the maximum value element present in the subarray[0 ... (i)]. The value of `maxElementIndex[0]=0`

Code for filling minElementIndex[0...n-1]

```
int index=minElementIndex[n-1];
for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
  minElementIndex[i] = index;
  if(arr[i]<arr[index])
      index=i;
}
```

Code for filling maxElementIndex[0 ... n-1]:

```
int index=maxElementIndex[0];
for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
  if(arr[i]>arr[index])
     index=i;
  maxElementIndex[i]=index;
}
```

Now, just iterate through both the arrays like in following way:

```
for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++){ 
    if(arr[maxElementIndex[i]]< minElementIndex[i]){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Let us dry run the proposed algorithm.

**Case 1:** `arr[5] = {5,-2,3,8,6}` `minElementIndex[5] = {1,2,4,4,4}` and `maxElementIndex[5] = {0,0,0,3,3}`. Clearly at `i=2`, `arr[maxElementIndex[i]] < arr[minElementIndex[i]]` which is `5 < 6`

**Case 2:** `arr[5] = {-5,3,-2,8,6}` `minElementIndex[5] = {2,2,4,4,4}` and `maxElementIndex[5] = {0,1,1,3,3}`. Clearly at `i=2`, `arr[maxElementIndex[i]] < arr[minElementIndex[i]]` which is `3 < 6`